# ROS Answers SE migration: rostopic pub

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

whenever I type in terminal:

```
rostopic pub call (/cmd_nose qbo_arduqbo/Nose [0,0,'test'] 2)
rostopic pub call (-1 /cmd_mouth qbo_arduqbo/Mouth [0,0,'test'] [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

my robot smiles and has a green nose LED lit.

But, when I type it in a rospy script, I get a syntax error.

HOW can I do this correctly. I have tried almost everything.
Thanks in Advance@@
:-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62895/rostopic-pub/) by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot just type commands into a python script. You'll need to use Python syntax. Check out the ROS beginner tutorials for the basics.

If you just want a script that lists commands, use a shell script.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2